# error E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/packages.microsoft.com_repos_vscode_dists_stable_InRelease

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-16.04

Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/packages.microsoft.com_repos_vscode_dists_stable_InRelease - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/packages.microsoft.com_repos_vscode_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable Release

Answer (score 0):

Press `Alt + F2` and paste software-properties-gtk (or you can open "Software Center" then go to "Edit" > "Software Sources"). Go to tab "Other Software", choose the duplicate entry and press the "Remove" button.

**https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable** main

Original Answer is define [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-w-duplicate-sources-list-entry):